# Tmux not sourcing my .tmux.conf

Tags: tmux

I installed tmux locally (without root priviledges). I also created my `.tmux.conf` file in my home directory with the following lines:

```
unbind-key C-b
set -g prefix C-o
bind-key C-o send-prefix
```

However, `tmux` does not seem to be sourcing this file (my bind key is still `C-b`). I have tried closing and re-opening my ssh session (this is on a remote machine) with no success.

What could be hapenning?

Comment: `tmux` is not `ssh`.  You need to restart `tmux`, or manually source the conf file yourself.  Restarting an `ssh` session won't do anything.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

It's most likely that you haven't started a new tmux server process.  You say that you've closed your ssh session and started a new one, but that wouldn't have any effect on the tmux server; one of the main benefits to using tmux is that sessions can survive that type of activity.

Try running `tmux ls` to check if the server is still running.  If it isn't it should complain about that.

If you instead get a list of sessions, attach to each of those in turn and close them.  The tmux server process will die when the last session is closed.  Then the next time that you start a new session a new server process will be created and it will read the `tmux.conf` file.

If you don't want to close the existing sessions you can ask the tmux server to read the configuration file with `tmux source ~/.tmux.conf`.

Comment: this saved me a lot of time. I didn't know new setting isn't sourced if there're existing sessions.

Answer (score 53):

Use `tmux kill-server`, after that start a **new** tmux session.

Comment: you save my day!

Comment: But please note that you will lose all open sessions / tab after killing the server.

Comment: i get "no server running"

Answer (score 36):

> This can also be done from within tmux, by pressing Ctrl+B (prefix key) and then : to bring up a command prompt, and typing:

```
:source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Read http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/reloading-tmux-config/

Answer (score 0):

As described in the other answers, if a `tmux` *server* process is already running, the configuration file will not be re-read when starting a new `tmux` *session*. Here’s the explanation from the `tmux` manual page:

> The configuration file is a set of tmux commands which are executed in
> sequence when the server is first started.  `tmux` loads configuration files
> once when the server process has started.  The `source-file` command may be
> used to load a file later.

Answer (score 0):

`tmux-256color` installation in Apple MacOS X is a bit different from Linux. Here is what needs to be done.

```
tmux kill-server
brew install ncurses
/usr/local/opt/ncurses/bin/infocmp tmux-256color > ~/tmux-256color.info
sudo tic -xe tmux-256color tmux-256color.info
nvim ~/.tmux.conf
set -s default-terminal 'tmux-256color'
```

More details:

- https://gist.github.com/joshuarli/247018f8617e6715e1e0b5fd2d39bb6c
- https://gpanders.com/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-using-tmux-256color-on-macos/

Answer (score -2):

You need to restart the tmux process
do it:
ps -axxx |  grep tmux
kill -9 #process

now start tmux and your .tmux.conf will work

Comment: Restarting the tmux sessions is exactly what the [existing, accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66607/117549) already says to do, though.  As you can see from the downvote that's already on the answer, the site's purpose is to collect distinct answers; please make sure yours are different from existing answers. Thanks, and welcome to U&L!