# tmux ignores the configuration files

Tags: linux, bash, configuration, tmux

`tmux` ignores the configuration files: both `/etc/tmux.conf` and `~/.tmux.conf`. Even I pass the path to the configuration file, using `tmux -f path/to/tmux.conf` it still doesn't load it.

The configuration file contains:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -g status-bg "#105C8D"
set -g status-fg white

set-window-option -g xterm-keys on

set -sg escape-time 0
```

I see that the status bar background is lightblue even the configuration sets it to dark blue (`#105C8D`). Also, 256 colors are not supported. That's why I guess the file is not loaded.

How can I fix the issue?

Running `tmux version 1.9a` but had the same issue with `1.8`, on Ubuntu 14.04.

I already saw:

- [Tmux not sourcing my .tmux.conf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/66606/95588)
- https://superuser.com/q/188491
- http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/reloading-tmux-config/
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/12069477

I don't get any errors regarding the config syntax.

Comment: What happens if you create a new `tmux.conf` file with the single line `set -g status-bg "#105C8D"` and run `tmux -f tmux.conf` ?

Comment: @janos I did the troubleshooting together with Cristian and we already tried this. The color is not changed...

Comment: I have already tried to create a new `tmux.conf` and run `tmux -f tmux.conf`, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution... which is probably not the best, but its working.
Open tmux with: `tmux -2` which force tmux to assume the terminal supports 256 colours.

Comment: Is this in gnome-terminal?

Comment: yes it is a gnome-terminal.